# How to set the animation when back to a ionic tab page from a certain page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I google this case for many solutions but no one can solve my problem.
Here is my problem:
I need to go to a detail page from some views,so I create a new router.

```
.state('detail',{
  url:"/detail/:msgId",
  templateUrl:"templates/detail.html",
  controller:"detailCtrl"
});
```

When I navigate to my detail page from home page, ionic don't display the back button on detail page and there is no animation,so I found this solution from [How to force Ionic display back button on certain page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598893/how-to-force-ionic-display-back-button-on-certain-page),and add nav-direction in home page :

home page:

```
<a ng-bind-html="item.text | linkformat" ui-sref="detail({msgId:'{{item.id}}'})" class="text" ﻿​nav-transition="ios" nav-direction="forward"></a>
```

detai page controller:

```
.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
viewData.enableBack = true;
});

})
```

so the back button display again,but when I click it and back to home page, the animation disappear again.I change the ion-nav-view like this,but it does not help.

```
<ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right">
```