# Ionic mobile app crashes after coming back from external link

Tags: ionic-framework

So I am building an app that embeds videos from vimeo.
These videos are our own created business related videos.

Now when I click on any of the links on the video,
i.e the play on vimeo site or Share or any button that ends in opening a URL in a inapp browser. 
It opens the link fine, but when I exit from the browser by pressing back button.
My App crashes throwing errors like some functions are not defined, or some google analytics functions are not defined. And the app has only white screen after that. I need to re-launch the app again.

Now unfortunately since these are the links on vimeo player, I do not have much say as to where I can open this link, using in app browser or external browser.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Below are the links to screenshots:

The video page: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxIXDOsrwoW9VVFOTklHQ3BLcUk
The In App Browser: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxIXDOsrwoW9dm9tb05IbkN1bmc

Ionic Discussion Forum Link: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/clicking-on-a-embedded-video-link-crashes-app/73554?u=vinayulphi

Comment: Share exact error . You can handle that error by handle of back button $scope.goBack = function(){
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
}  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598893/how-to-force-ionic-display-back-button-on-certain-page

Comment: The errors are related to few functions like analytics or a few functions that run during app.run not being initialized