# Ion-nav-bar for a view

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic 1 project. I'm trying to have a nav-bar with a back button inside one of the views, but its not appearing. I inspected on Chrome, and saw that the class of the back button became `hide`. Is there anyway I can make it appear?

Here's my code:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="GuDetailCtrl">
 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
<ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c show">
</ion-nav-back-button>
 </ion-nav-bar>
 <ion-content class="padding">
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Name</span>
    <span>{{hotel.name}}</span>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Locality</span>
    <span>{{hotel.locality}}</span>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Amenities</span>
    <span>{{hotel.amenities}}</span>
  </label>
</div>
<button class="button button-positive" ng-click="modal.show()">
  Create Booking
</button>

<script id="templates/booking.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">New Booking</h1>
      <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cancel</button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Check-in Date</span>
          <input ng-model="newBooking.inDate" type="date">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Check-out Date</span>
          <input ng-model="newBooking.outDate" type="date">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">No. of Rooms</span>
          <input ng-model="newBooking.rooms" type="number">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="createBooking(newBooking)">Create</button>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>

 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.The header has a class by default, if you don't explicitly specify one, then the back button won't show up. you can use **bar-light** or **bar-royal** in your class.

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-royal">
    <ion-nav-back-button>Back</ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

for more, You can see [here](https://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/YWZBdK)

Comment: This page is navigated to from another page. The parent page does not have a nav bar, so I can't have a common nav bar class. I tried using `bar-royal` in my code. The colour changed, but the back button still doesn't show up.

Comment: ok, I think you need to see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598893/how-to-force-ionic-display-back-button-on-certain-page) hope its help you.

Comment: I'm glad you got the solution.